# Methods to compute volume of a semi-algebraic region

Tags: integration, volume, real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

I am interested in a specific question involving the computation of the volume (perhaps area is more appropriate?) of a semi-algebraic region defined by a ternary quadratic form and a ternary cubic form. The question can be phrased more generally as follows. Let

$$\displaystyle Q(x,y,z) = a_1 x^2 - a_2 y^2 + a_3 z^2, a_i > 0 \text{ for } i = 1, 2, 3$$

be an indefinite ternary quadratic form with negative determinant and

$$\displaystyle T(x,y,z) = \sum_{\substack{i_1, i_2, i_3 \geq 0 \\ i_1 + i_2 + i_3 = 3}} b_{i_1, i_2, i_3} x^{i_1} y^{i_2} z^{i_3}$$

be a ternary cubic form with real coefficients. Let

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{R}_1 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : Q(x,y,z) = 1, |T(x,y,z)| < 2\},$$

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{R}_2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: Q(x,y,z) = -1, |T(x,y,z)| < 2\},$$

and

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{R}_3 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : T(x,y,z) = \pm 2, |Q(x,y,z)| < 1\}.$$

Are there known techniques to compute the volume (preferably give explicit formulas) of these regions?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106862/estimating-the-volume-of-a-semialgebraic-set-from-above

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. The exponent of $z$ should be 2; I fixed that

Comment: The answer in the math overflow question you linked only addresses compact semi-algebraic sets, and in the case I am interested in, the set is not necessarily compact.

Comment: Since you're in $\mathbb R^3$, you can plot the set defined by those polynomial inequalities. Then you can find where they intersect and write the boundary of the set as the union of patches of surfaces. Lastly, you can use the **divergence theorem** to compute the $3$-dimensional integral via the surface integral over each patch.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.2505